# how to cancel an append

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this script to append a set of input fields and it works fine and all but I need to have an option to remove/cancel an append without it affecting the other appended field. So for example, I click my append button 5 times, it gives me 5 set of input field but I decided to remove set 4. How do I go about this? My form data are being submitted to a mysql db.

Here is my append code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oncount = 0;
    $(function(){

    $('a#add_field_online').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();                                        
    oncount += 1;

    $('#activation').append(    
        '<div class="row-fluid">'
        +'<div class="span12" style="border-bottom:1px #dddddd; background-color:#cac6c6; ">'  
                +'<div style="float:left; width:5%;">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'
                +'<input type="radio" id="oprocess_where' + oncount + '" name="oprocess_where' + oncount + '" value="Online" checked >Online'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div style="float:left; width:7%">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'                    
                +'<select name="ostatus' + oncount + '" id="ostatus' + oncount + '" class="input-small">'
                +'<option value="Ghost">Ghost</option>'
                +'<option value="Actual">Actual</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div style="float:left; width: 7%">'
                +'<label>Type</label>'
                +'<select id="oupg' + oncount + '" name="oupg' + oncount + '" class="input-small" >'
                +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                +'<option value="Exp" >Exp</option>'
                +'<option value="Post" >Post</option>'
                +'<option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>'
                +'<option value="Retail" >Retail</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div style="float:left; width: 8%">'
                +'<label>F.U.D</label>'
                +'<input id="oupg_date' + oncount + '" name="oupg_date' + oncount + '"  type="text" class="input-small" />'
                +'</div> '

                +'<div style="float:left; width: 11%">'
                +'<label>Phone Used</label>'
                +'<select id="ophone_used' + oncount + '" name="ophone_used' + oncount + '" class="input-medium" >'
                    +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                    +'<option value="Basic" >Basic</option>'
                    +'<option value="LTE" >LTE</option>'
                    +'<option value="iPhone 4/4S" >iPhone 4/4S</option>'
                    +'<option value="iPhone LTE" >iPhone LTE</option>'
                    +'<option value="BlackBerry" >BlackBerry</option>'
                    +'<option value="3G/4G" >3G/4G</option>'
                    +'<option value="Data Block / Smartphone" >Data Block / Smartphone</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div id="odataBasic' + oncount + '" style="float:left; width: 12%;">'
                +'<label>Data Plan</label>'
                +'<select id="odata' + oncount + '" name="odata' + oncount + '" class="input-medium" >'
                    +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                    +'<option value="DDL" >DDL</option>'
                    +'<option value="DPPU" >DPPU</option>'
                    +'<option value="Data Block" >Data Block</option>'
                    +'<option value="$10" >$10</option>'
                    +'<option value="$15" >$15</option>'                        
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div id="odataSmart' + oncount + '" style="float:left; width: 12%; display: none;">'
                +'<label>Data Plan</label>'
                +'<select id="odatasmart' + oncount + '" name="odatasmart' + oncount + '" class="input-medium" >'
                    +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                    +'<option value="$15" >$15</option>'
                    +'<option value="$20" >$20</option>'
                    +'<option value="$25" >$25</option>'
                    +'<option value="$30" >$30</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div id="odivmessaging' + count + '" style="float:left; width: 11%">'
                +'<label>Messaging</label>'
                +'<select id="omessaging' + oncount + '" name="omessaging' + oncount + '" class="input-medium" >'
                    +'<option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                    +'<option value="$5" >$5</option>'
                    +'<option value="$10" >$10</option>'
                    +'<option value="$15" >$15</option>'
                    +'<option value="$20" >$20</option>'
                    +'<option value="$30" >$30</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div style="float:left; width: 8%">'
                +'<label>Rate Plan</label>'
                +'<input id="orate' + oncount + '" name="orate' + oncount + '"  type="text" class="input-small" />'
                +'</div> '

                +'<div style="float:left; width: 8%">'
                +'<label>Phone Number</label>'
                +'<input id="onumber_act' + oncount + '" name="onumber_act' + oncount + '" type="text" maxlength="10" class="input-small" />'
                +'</div>'


                +'<div style="float:left; width: 12%">'
                +'<label>Notes / Username </label>'
                +'<input id="onotes' + oncount + '" name="onotes' + oncount + '" type="text" class="input-medium"/>'
                +'<input type="hidden" name="oncounter[]" value="1">'
                +'</div>'
        +'</div>'   
        +'</div>'   
         ); 
    $("#ophone_used"+ oncount).change(function(){
    if ($("#ophone_used"+ oncount).val() == "Basic") {
        ('#odataBasic'+ oncount).show();
        $('#odataSmart'+ oncount).hide();
        } else {
        $('#odataBasic'+ oncount).hide();
        $('#odataSmart'+ oncount).show();   
    }
    });
    });

});
```

And here is my append button

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="add_field"><span>Add In-Store Activation</span></a>
```

My SQL submit

```
if(is_array($_POST[oncounter]))
 {
$oncount=count($_POST[oncounter]);

for($o=0;$o<=$oncount;$o++)
{       
    $oprocess_where = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["oprocess_where".$o.""])));
    $ostatus = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["ostatus".$o.""])));
    $oupg = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["oupg".$o.""])));
    $oupg_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["oupg_date".$o.""]));
    $ophone_used = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["ophone_used".$o.""])));
    $odata = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["odata".$o.""])));
    $odatasmart = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["odatasmart".$o.""])));
    $omessaging = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["omessaging".$o.""])));
    $orate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["orate".$o.""])));
    $onumber_act = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["onumber_act".$o.""])));
    $onotes = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["onotes".$o.""])));

    $oorderStatus = "Pending";
    $oinstore= 0; 
    $oonline = 1; 
    $opending = 1;

    if($oprocess_where !="")
    {
    $query="insert into phone_details (process_where, status, upg, upg_date, phone_used, data, datasmart, messaging, rate, number_act, notes, dealID, custID, orderStatus, online, instore, pending) 
values ('".$oprocess_where."','".$ostatus."','".$oupg."','".$oupg_date."','".$ophone_used."','".$odata."','".$odatasmart."','".$omessaging."','".$orate."','".$onumber_act."','".$onotes."', '$dealID', $custID, '$oorderStatus', $oonline, $oinstore, $opending)";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should change the div id to a class since the may be multiple divs added and ids are required to be unique.

Comment: First of all I would remove all that HTML as js and use `clone()` on a  hidden version of it in actual HTML

Answer (score 1):

Add a button somewhere in that div

```
$('#activation').append(    
    '<div class="row-fluid removethisrow"><button class="remove">Remove</button>'
```

Pre-bind that button using `.on()` (in the way that `.live()` would work), so this JQ can go outside of the append func.

```
$('#activation').on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.removethisrow').remove();
});
```

...

But I wouldn't use `name="ostatus' + oncount + '"` I'd put that value in the row's div in case I need to target things within it

```
$('#activation').append(    
    '<div class="row-fluid removethisrow" id="oncount_' + oncount + '"><button class="remove">Remove</button>'
```

and use a post array, so the oncount isn't actually relevant once it's sent to the server.

Either

```
    <input type="radio" name="oprocess_where[]" class="oprocess_where" ... />
```

and

```
if(is_array($_POST[oprocess_where])) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['oprocess_where']); $i++){
        $oprocess_where = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["oprocess_where"][$i])));
        $ostatus = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["ostatus"][$i])));
```

or

```
    <input type="radio" name="rows[]['oprocess_where']" class="oprocess_where" ... />
```

and

```
if(is_array($_POST[rows])) {
    foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
        $oprocess_where = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($row["oprocess_where"])));
        $ostatus = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($row["ostatus"])));
```

...

But then I wouldn't do `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities` more than once

```
foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
    foreach (explode(' ','oprocess_where ostatus oupg oupg_date etc')) as $allowed) {
        $insert[$allowed]=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($row[$allowed])));
    }
    $sql='INSERT INTO phone_details ('.implode(array_keys($insert)).') VALUES ('.implode($insert).')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a remove function and then attach an onclick event to everything you append. So something like:

```
function removeElm(elm)
{
    $(elm).remove();
}
```

and then when you append, add something like:

```
<div onclick="removeElm(this)" id="features_remove" style="float:left; width: 11%; margin-left:115px;" >
```

Comment: how will this affect my counter? I edited my original post to include my full append script and my sql submit